# Why the download speed becomes slow than before in cloud server (Digital Ocean droplet with Cloudflare CDN)?

Tags: cloudflare, digital-ocean

A cloud server (Digital Ocean droplet with Cloudflare CDN) runs a Wordpress website that hosts a software download for its visitors. One day, users report that their download only runs with 30kb/s, where before it ran easily with >5mb/s. A first check in your browser shows the site to run smoothly, but the download is reproducably slow. Via FTP, the download is fast.

Which steps should I take to track and fix this behaviour?

Comment: This sounds like a WordPress.stackezchange.com question.  (Backup first then) try disabling all plugins and see if speed increases.  If it does find the plugin that's causing it...

Comment: @davidgo, actually no this not a wordpress issue, its server issue. WordPress site loads fine, speed is fine but to download software/digital media from the site is slow. download speed less than or equals to 30kbs/s. Before it was more than 5mb/s. I suppose server set the download speeds. But not sure where to look.

Comment: I'd be surprised if its a server issue - although I could conceive it being a provider issue. What happens if you download a file without going through WordPress? What happens if you download the file from WordPress but bypass cloudflare?

Comment: We did disable cloudflare but still slow download. We can download via FTP and its fast.

Comment: What happens if you download the file via http without going through WordPress?